# Determinants of free modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

This should be easy, but I'm stuck.

> Let $A$ be a DVR and $B$ a finite algebra over $A$ that is free as an $A$-module. For $b \in B$ one can define the norm of $b$ as the determinant of multiplication by $b$ on $B$. Suppose that there is a basis $f_1, \ldots, f_n$ of $B$ over $A$ and $n$ elements $a_i \in A$ such that $a_1f_1, \ldots, a_n f_n$ is a basis of the free $A$-module $bB$. Then, one should show that $N(b) = a_1 \cdots a_n$. How can this be done?

Regards,
Heidar

Comment: Oh sorry - Assume that bB is free of the same rank!

Comment: YACP: exactly ! I will edit. Do you see how to do the problem?

Comment: Why two downvotes?

Comment: It is not true that $N(b)=\prod_{i=1}^n a_i$. Clearly, we can replace $a_1$ by $-a_1$ and all the assumptions still holds.

Comment: YACP: B is an integral domain, sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

Multiplication by $b$ has image $bB$ and sends the basis $\{f_1,\dots,f_n\}$ to $\{bf_1,\dots,bf_n\}$. This is also an $A$-basis of $bB$ (why?). Now write $bf_i=\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}a_jf_j$, where $A=(a_{ij})$ is an invertible matrix. Then $N(b)=a_1\cdots a_n\det A$. (Note that since $A$ is invertible, then $\det A$ is an invertible element of $A$.)

**Edit.** As noted @Jiangwei Xue in his comment to the question this is the maximum we can get.